# Mouse movement left - right uneven in distance

Tags: mouse

I have an issue with my mouse after cleaning it (razor mamba tournament edition).

When i move to the left and to the right for the same distance a couple of times, my mouse ends up moving more to the left than to the right.

I assumed I broke something in the mouse, so i tried this with another mouse (logitech wireless mouse), same result. Note that nothing changed to the surface I use to move the mouse on.

System restore didn't help either.

Before cleaning the mouse i never had this problem, so i assume the mouse must have changed some settings? Any ideas? I am using windows 10

Comment: Are you using this on a uniform surface? It might be worth repeating the test on a sheet of paper or something, as odd pits or cracks on the surface you're using it on could cause different results. Cleaning your mouse shouldn't have made the behavior different for another mouse.

Comment: I tried using different surfaces. Same result. This also didn't change pre cleaning the mouse. This is why i started thinking that the gaming mouse could have changed some internal settings as a "correction" to damage i could have caused while cleaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, mouse movement is translated acceleration-sensitive, meaning that if you physically accelerate the mouse faster, it moves logically overproportionally more. For example a very slow movement of one inch might translate to 100 pixels on the screen, and a jerking of one inch might translate to a move across the whole screen.

There is a good chance that your hand movement is accelerating differently to the right and to the left, so that could be the reason for the observed discrepancy.

You can switch that behavior off in the mouse settings completely; then your test makes sense. Alternatively, turn the mouse heads up and repeat the test; if the discrepancy is now to the other side, it is your asymmetric accelerated hand movement.

If your mouse is above the 7.95$ class, it might have a similar behavior built in, but it should be controllable via the device driver/setting. Just make sure to check on the OS level *and* in the device specific settings.

Comment: turning the mouse upside down does indeed reverse the issue. I disabled the enhance pointer precision option but the issue still remains.